# MATLAB: empty plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot this function in MATLAB: `(x.^2 - 2*x + 1)/(x.^2 - x - 2)`

but I am getting an empty graph everytime I run this code. Does anyone know why?

Here is my code:

```
x = 1:0.01:4;
y = (x.^2 - 2*x + 1)/(x.^2 - x - 2);
plot(x,y);
```

Comment: There is an error message displayed in the command window, because your second line contains an error. Element-wise division is `./`, not `/`

Comment: For some reason, my command window did not display any errors. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @qp55 That's most likely because you are using MATLAB R2016b and so broadcasting was performed. If you tried using this code in any other version of MATLAB, you would get an error. I have a love-hate relationship with automatic broadcasting in the latest MATLAB version.

Answer (score 0):

y is only 1 value.
Add a dot before the division

y = (x.^2 - 2*x + 1)./(x.^2 - x - 2);